# How do I add access controls to named routes in config/routes.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use `require_admin!` frequently in my controllers. It works great.

Now, I want to add named route like so:

```
# config/routes.rb
match "poniesandrainbows" => redirect("https://poniesandrainbows.com")
# ^sadly, not really a website, btw.^
```

How do I restrict access to that route? Is this possible? Obviously it redirects to a public URL, but I still want to keep the route private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot restrict access from routes.

The safest way to match "poniesandrainbows" with a controller where you can use require_admin! and then redirect them to the public url.

You can try to solve the problem on the front end. Maybe only show the link to admin users. 
It won't stop other users to paste the link directly to their browser url though

Answer (score 1):

That kind of functionality should be encapsulated in the controller. The router handles the plumbing of passing a request to the correct controller. It is the controller's job to correctly figure out how to process the request. In this cause, the controller would use the auth service (such as require_admin!) to determine if the user is allowed to be redirected or if they are doom to another fate.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually possible although as the other posters mentioned very rarely a good idea. You can read about how in this blog post: (scroll down to the routes section)

http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2011/05/31/user-centric-routing-in-rails-3/

Comment: That's pretty gross *and* cool. ;) I might actually do something like this as it's a pretty weird case that I need it for...